# Excel Vlookup table array is throwing NA error

Tags: excel, vlookup

We have office 365 version 16.0.12430. Getting "#N/A" error with Vlookup to a table range, whereas a single column Vlookup working fine.

Actual Table on Sheet 4

[image]

on Sheet 5, doing the validation

[image]

Column "ID Vlookup"  formula is VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet4!$B$2:$B$6,1,FALSE)

Column Name Vlookup formula is VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet4!$A$2:$B$6,1,FALSE)

Verified the columns format and spaces as well, still failing with "N/A" error.

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH. You can't use VLOOKUP here.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` can only see columns to the right of (*and inclusive of*) the column you are matching against. Since you are matching ID to the name (which is to the left of ID), this will not work. Have to either restructure table (swap the columns on sheet 4) or use `INDEX/MATCH` as mentioned above which will let you match columns in any direction